# Navigating to other views in code from a SurfaceView

Tags: android

Im experienced iOS dev but new to Android dev and asking some newbie questions here...

I am making a app that does a lot of custom drawing of png's and animations and has no standard UI elements at all, and I have choosen to go down the SurfaceView road. I handle all the detection on what is touched in my SurfaceView code also.

But how on earth do I handle navigation between views from within my SurfaceView code? How do I e.g. navigate to a activity called QuizActivity? In a "normal" view/activity I do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), QuizActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I do not have access to getBaseContext and startActivity from within my SurfaceView, and even if I did would doing this result in multiple views loaded at the same time?

Bottom line: How do I implement this navigation manually in my code from within my SurfaceView?

Thank you

Søren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your surface view just call:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), QuizActivity.class);
    getContext().startActivity(intent)
```

every view have a reference to the context they're running, and the context can always start new activities, services, get the resources, etc.

**edit**

on your surfaceview you include this:

```
    private SurfaceCallbacks listener;

    public interface SurfaceCallbacks{
       public void onTouch(/* any data you want to pass to the activity*/);
    }

    public void registerSurfaceCallbacksListener(SurfaceCallbacks l){
       listener = l;
    }

    // and then whenever the surface being touched and you want to call something outside of the surface you do:

    if(listener!=null)
       listener.onTouch(/* pass the parameters you declared on the interface */);
```

and on the activity that holds the surface you do this:

```
    public ActivityThatHoldsSurface extends Activity implements SurfaceCallbacks{

       // that comes form the surface
       @Override
       onTouch(/* your parameters */){
          // do the navigation stuff
       }

       // and immediately after you inflate or instantiate your surface you do:
       mySurface.registerSurfaceCallbacksListener(ActivityThatHoldsSurface.this);

    }
```

does it make sense???

Comment: Then I get this error: "E/StrictMode(1502): class com.some.Class; instances=2; limit=1", is that because I am trying to navigate "back" to the activity where I navigate from to the activity holding the SurfaceView? I have seen this error before, there seems to be some stuff for me to learn about how those activities are loaded and released, any pointers here?

Comment: I've never seen this message but probably that is the reason. But it seems that you're mixing the concepts of activity  and a view. Even if your view is the whole screen, it's still inside an activity. I reckon that best thing on this point you're now is to take a step back. create an interface, make your activity that is holding the view implement that interface, and create a public void setTouchCallbackListener(TouchInterface l){ } on your view for the activity to register itself to receive those callbacks. If you don't know what it means, let me know and I'll post some code.

Comment: Busius, yes please update your answer with a example if you have the time, Im not sure I know what you mean here.